# Joining values from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: sql, pivot, crosstab

There are 3 tables:

```
1. Users (id1, ..., username, ....)
2. Equipment (id2, id3, ...., equipmentname, ...)
3. Equipmentlist (id4, ...., equipmenttype, equipmentname, ...)
```

`where id1 = id2, id3 = id4`. Every user has from 1 to 4 kinds of equipment.

Is there a way to make a table where every user has all his equipment added in one row, like (username, equipmenttype1, equipmentname1, ....,  equipmenttype4, equipmentname4)?

Here's an example:

table Users:

```
id1 Username
1   user1
2   user2
3   user3
```

table Equipment:

```
id2 id3 equipmentname
1   235 PG4
1   236 Bosch 4000
3   451 GM200
```

table Equipmentlist:

```
id4 Equipmenttype     Equipmentname
235 Cooker            PG4
236 Hot water boiler  Bosch 4000
451 Gas Meter         GM200
```

I want something like this:

```
id1 username equipmenttype1 equipmentname1 equipmenttype2     equipmentname2 .... equipmenttypeN equipmentnameN
1   user1    Cooker         PG4            Hot water boiler   Bosch 4000
2   user2
3   user3    Gas Meter      GM200
```

Comment: Maybe you should try PIVOT? I don't know which database you use.

Comment: Please tag database you are using, also add table structure in text format with column names, and expected output. Finally, users expect to see any effort u have made to solve this and we will help improve the query

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is totally unclear how the tables are related to each other.

Comment: Can you please be specific in expected result instead of using `...` with exact column names to be derived from above 3 tables